# php mysqli looping too many results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having a little issue with looping through my database retrieving results, I understand why I am getting the issue but not too sure on how to implement the solution  as my PHP is not the greatest.
I have looked through the forums but couldn't find anything to address my problem.

From below my output would give me 12 results when only I want 6 results 2 items each: for each loop is counting 12 items in array which makes sense so it will out put 12 times giving me duplicates of each. how am I best to handle this issue.

```
    MyTable1:                          myTable2:
    |   ID   |  Name  |           | NameID   |       Details     |   
    |--------|--------|           |----------|-------------------|
    |   0    | bob    |           |   0      | lives in the city |
    |   1    | david  |           |   1      | lives in a caravan|
    -------------------           --------------------------------
```

My MSQLI query:

```
     $qryRandom   =  "SELECT  MyTable1.ID,  MyTable2.Details
                      FROM  MyTable1
                      INNER JOIN  MyTable2
                      ON MyTable1.ID=MyTable2.NameID 
                      ORDER BY RAND()
                      LIMIT 6;";
```

My PHP( generall example).

```
    $resultR= $con->query($qryRandom) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultR, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    foreach ( $row as $key=>$value ){ // loops 12 times here as there is 6 items x 2 values
    echo $key.": ".$value."<br>";

    }

 }
```

result outputs:

```
    bob lives in city
    bob lives in city
    David lives in caravan
    David lives in caravan
    john lives in the car 
    john lives in the car  // doubles of each entry is my issue
   // hope I was thorough and provided enough info for my scenario.
```

Comment: your "general example" contradicts with verbose description. Which renders whole question not a real one

Comment: the query you provided cannot produce such output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with works how ever I am still not happy with it;

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultR, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {
    for ($i = 0; $i<1;$i++){
    echo $row['name'].$row['details']."<br>";
    }
    }
```

Im more then sure there is a better approach to this issue.